# Insert a geometry in a PostGres DB from a GeoJSON text with Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I've got a GeoJSON file and I need to import the geometries into a Postgres Db with Python.
I tried this:

```
...
cursor = conn.cursor()
data = json.load(json_file)
for row in data['features']
    geometry = row['geometry']
    params = (geometry)
    cursor.callproc('ST_GeomFromGeoJSON', params)
    wkb_geometry = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    sql = "INSERT INTO tbl(wkb_geometry) VALUES (%s)"
    val = (wkb_geometry)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    conn.commit()
...
```

I get this error:

```
function st_geomfromgeojson(typt => unknown, coordinates => numeric[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM ST_GeomFromGeoJSON("type":='Polygon',"coordina...

HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any idea? I don't know how to add explicit type casts as suggested.

Comment: It's probably better to convert the GeoJSON to a Shapely geometry and push that to the DB using psycog - Your best bet for debugging this is to look in the Postgres log and see what the whole SQL statement is

Comment: @IanTurton thanks but I have to download data and schedule it. Python seems to be the best way to do this in my environment

Comment: Shapely is a python library, though actually `ogr2ogr` would be esier

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution (very simple): I only have to convert JSON data to string with `JSON.dumps()` and run a simple insert SQL.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
data = json.load(json_file)
for row in data['features']
    geometry = json.dumps(row['geometry'])
    
    sql = "INSERT INTO tbl(wkb_geometry) VALUES (ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s))"
    val = (wkb_geometry)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    conn.commit()
...
```